# Android How to send my file from SD card to 192.168.1.100:8080?

Tags: android

How to send my file from SD card to 192.168.1.100:8080?
To show in my browser?

my file is: sd_card/aaa.jpg

i can send a jpg file what is on my assets folder:

host        = getLocalIpAddress();

```
                        send("<head>" +
                                "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" " +
                                "href=\""+host+"/css.css\" />" +

                                "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" value=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2\">Második oldal " +
                                "<img src='"+host+"/icon.png'>" +
                                "<br><a href='/takepicture'>take picture</a><div id='asd' style='clear:left'>0</div> "+
                                js+"</head>");
```

but how can send a file from SD_CARD not from ASSETS?

Thanks, 
Leslie

Comment: You want to load a HTML page in your browser which loads images from your SD card?

Comment: yes, i have a serversocket:              serversocket = new ServerSocket(port);
             serversocket.setReuseAddress(true); and a client clientsocket = serversocket.accept();

Answer (score 1):

Finally I made it!!!

source codes here:

http://code.google.com/p/android-simple-httpserver-camerapicture/